# How to make Docker postgresql logs more specific?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using the official postgresql:13 DockerHub image and intialize a database using an .SQL file at /var/lib/postgresql/data.
While that works, it is hard to debug because docker/docker-compose is very vague:

```
...
docker-postgresql-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/hito.sql
docker-postgresql-1  | DROP SCHEMA
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE SCHEMA
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | INSERT 0 3
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | INSERT 0 9
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TYPE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE FUNCTION
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TRIGGER
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE
...
```

Is there some way to get Postgres to be more specific about what it is doing? For example, it should look like:

```
docker-postgresql-1  | DROP SCHEMA MYSCHEMA
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE MYTABLE1
docker-postgresql-1  | INSERT 0 3 INTO TABLE MYTABLE1, 1 skipped because it already exists but not aborted due to  ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE MYTABLE2
docker-postgresql-1  | INSERT 0 9 INTO TABLE MYTABLE2, ALL SUCCESSFULL
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TYPE MYTABLE
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE MYTABLE3
docker-postgresql-1  | CREATE TABLE MYTABLE4
```

I could emulate some of that using \echo statements but not all of it. Is there some way to make Postgresql less secretive and give me more details about what exactly is happening on database initialization? Some of my tables are empty and the logs it is giving me by default are not enough to find out what happens. However it should also not give me thousands of lines of successfull SQL insert statements, only a summary and when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to start your postgres instance with `"log_statement=all"` argument. Example:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

    db:
      image: postgres:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]  # override entrypoint command with log_statement argument
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This will provide more granularity for the logs:

```
postgres-db-1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
postgres-db-1       | 2021-11-28 12:34:50.704 UTC [63] LOG:  statement: CREATE USER myUser;
postgres-db-1       | CREATE ROLE
postgres-db-1       | 2021-11-28 12:34:50.705 UTC [63] LOG:  statement: CREATE DATABASE dev_db;
postgres-db-1       | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-db-1       | 2021-11-28 12:34:50.769 UTC [63] LOG:  statement: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dev_db TO myUser;
postgres-db-1       | GRANT
postgres-db-1       | 2021-11-28 12:34:50.770 UTC [63] LOG:  statement: CREATE DATABASE myApp_test;
postgres-db-1       | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-db-1       | 2021-11-28 12:34:50.817 UTC [63] LOG:  statement: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dev_db TO myUser;
postgres-db-1       | GRANT
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is too verbose. If I insert 1000 rows, it will print all of them. However it is good to have for debugging specific problems, thanks!